# window.open() does nothing in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, window.open

i can't use target=_blank because my actions are build dynamically, example: when user clicks on the link, i catch it with .click(function(event), than ajax api is called and then in the callback i have the url where to go.

Now the problem:

window.location = mylink; // WORKS - OK!
window.open(mylink); // DOES NOT WORK - NOT OK!

why?

I need to open a new window because mylink is a link to a pdf file, and when using window.location the pdf file is correctly viewed, but,..without any back navigation controls of the browser. It's a mobile webapp, and i use jquery mobile.

Too bad on the internet many others have the pdf viewer problem but no one has solved it, so i figured out to open a new window and pass the pdf link there. This way my parent window would stay untouched. Otherwise, you have to kill the current session and open safari again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add target="_blank" to your links. Then, call this script on click event.
It will open your pdf in new window.

```
$( "a" ).live( "click", function(event) {
    var $this = $(this),
        //get href, remove same-domain protocol and host
        href = $this.attr( "href" ).replace( location.protocol + "//" + location.host, ""),
        //if target attr is specified, it's external, and we mimic _blank... for now
        target = $this.is( "[target]" ),
        //if it still starts with a protocol, it's external, or could be :mailto, etc
        external = target || /^(:?\w+:)/.test( href ) || $this.is( "[rel=external]" ),
        target = $this.is( "[target]" );

    if( href === '#' ){
        //for links created purely for interaction - ignore
        return false;
    }

    var testtarget = $this.attr( "target" );
    if (testtarget == '_blank') {
        alert('Leaving web app');
        return true;
    }

    $activeClickedLink = $this.closest( ".ui-btn" ).addClass( $.mobile.activeBtnClass );

    if( external || !$.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled ){
        //remove active link class if external
        removeActiveLinkClass(true);

        //deliberately redirect, in case click was triggered
        if( target ){
            window.open(href);
            //return true;
        }
        else{
            location.href = href;
        }
    }
    else {  
        //use ajax
        var transition = $this.data( "transition" ),
            back = $this.data( "back" ),
            changeHashOnSuccess = !$this.is( "[data-rel="+ $.mobile.nonHistorySelectors +"]" );

        nextPageRole = $this.attr( "data-rel" );    

        //if it's a relative href, prefix href with base url
        if( href.indexOf('/') && href.indexOf('#') !== 0 ){
            href = getBaseURL() + href;
        }

        href.replace(/^#/,'');

        changePage(href, transition, back, changeHashOnSuccess);            
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a dialog/popup in jQuery Mobile you have to use an attribute `data-rel="dialog"` and the `href` attribute must point to a URL you want to load

```
<a href="yourpage.html" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog</a>
```

Comment: May be be the answer to the question, but is the correct solution to the problem.

Comment: thx - if you have read my question then you have understood i'm not interested in opening dialogs/windows directly trough links (<a href="...">) but rather programmatically within the script like window.open() -> but this does not work and that's why i asked the question